# Add headers to lines according to column

Tags: awk, grep

I have the following input

```
a b danny
c d joe
1 4 danny
d 5 dana
e f joe
t 4 dana
```

I would like to sort by last column, and add it as a header to each group of lines.
The output should be (order of groups is not important) in Linux:

```
dana
d 5 dana
t 4 dana
danny
a b danny
1 4 danny
joe
c d joe
e f joe
```

Can it be done using (e)grep / sed / awk and other command line tools?

Comment: What have you tried? You have listed two of the tools that can be used to do this. Have you read their man pages or used Google to find out ways to get what you want?

Comment: @NasirRiley - I tried all tools, but i may miss something. didn't read the man page, but googled it. didn't come out with anything

Comment: Edit your question with what you tried and include what isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using GNU coreutils `sort` and `awk`:

```
$ sort -sk3 file | awk '$3!=group{ group=$3; print group }1'
dana
d 5 dana
t 4 dana
danny
a b danny
1 4 danny
joe
c d joe
e f joe
```

Sort the input file on the 3rd field (`-k3`) using stable (`-s`) sort, then pipe the output to `awk` and print the 3rd field on its own line if it didn't change. Then print the current record (`1`).

Answer (score 2):

Since you state that the output order is not important, you can build an associative array of the records, keyed on the value of the last field; then at the end print the key and value:

```
awk '
  {a[$NF] = a[$NF] (a[$NF] ? ORS : "") $0} 
  END {for (i in a){print i; print a[i]}}
' file
joe
c d joe
e f joe
dana
d 5 dana
t 4 dana
danny
a b danny
1 4 danny
```

or prepend the key to the value the first time you see it:

```
awk '
  {a[$NF] = (($NF in a) ? a[$NF] : $NF) ORS $0} 
  END {for (i in a) print a[i]}
' file
joe
c d joe
e f joe
dana
d 5 dana
t 4 dana
danny
a b danny
1 4 danny
```

If you *do* want to sort the groups, and have GNU awk > 4.0 you can do so via the `PROCINFO[]` structure:

```
gawk '
  {a[$NF] = (($NF in a) ? a[$NF] : $NF) ORS $0}
  END {PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"; for (i in a) print a[i]}
' file
dana
d 5 dana
t 4 dana
danny
a b danny
1 4 danny
joe
c d joe
e f joe
```